# "Faking" table rows with divs and spans?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to create some "table rows" using `<div>` and `<span>`. (Why not use actual table rows? Because I want to set rounded corners on each table row using the awesome [jquery corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/), and it doesn't seem to like table rows.)

I'd like three-cell rows, with LH and RH cells of fixed width, and a central cell of fluid width, in which the text should wrap.

```
[fixedwidth][wrapwrapwrapwrap          ][fixedwidth]

[fixedwidth][wrapwrapwrapwrapwrapwrapwr][fixedwidth]
             apwrapwrapwrapwrapwrapwr

[fixedwidth][wrapwrapwrapwrap          ][fixedwidth]
```

This is what I have so far, but it's disastrously wrong:

```
<html> 
<head>
<style>
.table-row {
    width:100%;
}
.cell1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.cell2 {
    float: left;
}
.cell3 {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div class='table-row'>
<span class="cell1">Title</span>
<span class="cell2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
<span class="cell3">Available</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The central text doesn't wrap, and pushes down onto the next line.

Please could anyone advise?

Comment: You could use a div wrapped around your table to give the impression of rounded corners instead of this craziness.

Comment: I want to round the corners on each row individually (have edited question to clarify this). I guess I could use a div around each row, or inside each row - if that's valid HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell1, .cell2, .cell3 {
    display: table-cell;
}
.cell1, .cell3 {
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks again... just one more thing - do you know how I can make cell3 'float' right, so that the central column is truly liquid?

Comment: Well, the cells will behave as normal table cells and fill the row, so you need to make the .table-row have a width of 100% (or an appropriate pixel value).

Comment: @Kalessin  I don't think that is cross browser compliant.  While it would work in some, I think in IE (as usual) you are only allowed display:block/display:inline

Comment: ie 6 and 7 do not support css tables

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: That's almost certainly true of older versions of Internet Explorer, but this method works in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it doesn't make sense to float inline elements. Secondly, that's not how you create a liquid column.

Try these changes:

```
<div class="cell1">Title</div>
<div class="cell3">Available</div>
<div class="cell2">consequat.</div>
```

and

```
.cell2 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Note: If you add padding/borders/margins to the cells don't forget to add the sum of the sizes to `margin-left` and `margin-right` for `cell2`.

Comment: You *can* float inline elements.

Comment: @Kalessin You're right. You can float them. But if you do that they are converted automatically to block elements. So, in fact, you *can* float them, but it doesn't make sense for them to be inline in the first place.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't make sense to float the span elements in the question, but floating img elements would allow text to flow around them. So, it does make sense to float *some* inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add divs and spans inside regular table cells?

Edit:

```
<tr>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I want each table row to have rounded corners. Could I do `<tr><div><td></td><td></td><td></td></div></tr>`, or would this be invalid HTML?

Comment: No, doesn't seem to work - the `<div>` appears in a completely different part of the page...

Comment: @AP257 *Inside* cells. I've updated the answer with an example.