# CSS when combining tables, divs and spans

Tags: html, css, html-table, django-templates

I have a list of items I want to display in a table (because I want to leverage the styling from bootstrap).  But because I am having issues [making the table sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772569/use-jquery-sortable-with-hidden-table-rows-in-django-template) I want each row to essentially contain two rows, one information row and one detail row.

The information row will have some status icons and the item name.  The detail row will have any quantity of text.

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615348/faking-table-rows-with-divs-and-spans) to create two div/span rows within each table row:

```
<style>
    .table-row {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .data_column {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .icon_column {
        width: 20px;
        display: table-cell;
    }
</style>

<table class="table table-condensed>
    <thead>
        <tr class="table_header">
            <th>
                <div class='table-row'>
                    <span class="icon_column"><i class="icon-ok"></i></span>
                    <span class="icon_column"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i></span>
                    <span class="icon_column"></span>
                    <span class="data_column">Name</span>
                    <span class="data_column">Date</span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for action in actions %}
            <tr class="item_row">
                <td>
                    <div class='table-row'>
                        <span class="icon_column"><input type="checkbox"></span>
                        <span class="icon_column"><i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"></i></span>
                        <span class="icon_column"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign icon-green"></i></span>
                        <span class="data_column">{{ action }}</span>
                        <span class="data_column">{{ action.previous_reset_date|date:"M d" }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='table-row'>
                        <span>{{ action.notes|apply_markup:"creole" }}</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My issue is that the second "table-row" is displaying like an individual column.  It doesn't span the width of the entire table.  If this were a strict table, I would need to do something like colspan="5".  How do I change the css so that this portion:

```
<div class='table-row'>
    <span>{{ action.notes|apply_markup:"creole" }}</span>
</div>
```

is the width of the entire table row?

Comment: Just an idea, but what happens with `<div class='table-row' style='width:100%'>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove the class from the second div row, it works fine.

```
<div>
    <span>{{ action.notes|apply_markup:"creole" }}</span>
</div>
```